# Proof of Riesz Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

[Here](https://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/07/17/rieszs-lemma/) is the proof of the Riesz Lemma.

When the author show that $\| z-y \| \geq \theta$, I don't understand the following step:

$$\dfrac{1}{\| v-y_0 \|} \| v-y_0 - (\| v-y_0 \|)y \| \geq \dfrac{\alpha}{\| v-y_0 \|}$$

How to obtain the above step?

Comment: $y_0+\Vert v-y_0\Vert y\in Y$ and $\inf_{y\in Y} \Vert v-y\Vert=a$.

Comment: Awh I can't believe I mislook this fact....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$v - y_0 - (||v-y_0||)y$ is of the form $v - y'$ with $y' \in Y$ (as $Y$ is a subspace, and $y, y_0 \in Y$).

The norm of it is thus bounded below by $\alpha$ by the definition of $\alpha$ as $\inf_{y \in Y} ||v - y||$.

Comment: Aren’t they (including summation and scalar product) properties of vector subspace? Is only subspace enough for using them? Thanks in advance

Comment: @esrabasar a subspace means vector subspace in the lemma. So $Y$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: I didn’t know that it means vector subspace. It is same in my lecture notes it says only subspace hence I’m confused while studying. You have clarified very thanks sir

Comment: @esrabasar [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma) also states it as a vector subspace (follow the link in the first mention of subspace).

Comment: I’ve realized that thanks to your reply. Also I will glance wikipedia. Sincerely

Comment: @esrabasar Glad to be able to help.